# Interpret randomForest Call Results

Tags: r, random-forest

My model Call of randomForest is :

```
Call:
 randomForest(formula = medv ~ ., data = training_set, ntree = 100,      set.seed = 500) 

Type of random forest: regression
Number of trees: 100
No. of variables tried at each split: 4

Mean of squared residuals: 0.1200638
% Var explained: 87.96
```

How do we interpret all these numbers? any suggestions about  No. of variables tried at each split? should I increase it?

```
Mean of squared residuals: 0.1200638
% Var explained: 87.96
```

How do we interpret these two? lower, higher? which better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the two evaluation metrics that you have mentioned?

Mean of squared residuals - the lower the better because it is the mean of square of errors(residuals)

Var explained - The higher the better as it `variance of predicted values / variance of actual values`

Let me know if the above solves your problem or you need any further clarification of the metrics.

Comment: Var explained - The higher the better as it variance of predicted values / variance of actual values  this! I was looking for this. so it compares the prediction results with the test set? you say? this is the main ratio we are seeking for?   thank you so much

Comment: You can have these score for both test and train data.